# adb backup file size 1 kb

Tags: android, adb

I am facing problem in backup my wechat i tried

```
adb backup -noapk com.tencent.mm
```

It successfully opend the backup screen on my device but when the backup process completed i got backup.ab file with 1 kb size, i also tried to unpack it using this command

```
java -jar abe.jar unpack backup.ab backup.tar <password>
```

but it is showing me

Strong AES encryption allowed

Magic: ANDROID BACKUP

Version: 2

Compressed: 1

Algorithm: none

1024 bytes written to backup.tar.

and the backup.tar file size remains 1 kb

i tried many blogs but coudn`t get success. Anyone please help me i want to open backup.tar and want to get the data inside it.

Comment: what is your goal here? to extract the apk file from your device?

Comment: I want to extract wechat sqlite db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer probably wechat newer version doesn`t allow backup
i.e.they must have used

```
allowBackup="false"
```

in it`s manifest.

Comment: Any idea what version of WeChat does not have that flag set? Idea would be to downgrade the WeChat version (via cloud backup) and then use adb backup on that version. But the downgraded version would also have to support cloud backup.

Comment: try wechat version lower than 6.0